# Android Broadcast from Service To Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send a Broadcast from a service out to an Activity.  I can verify the broadcast is sent from within the service, but the Activity doesn't pick up anything.

Here is the relevant service code:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(NEW_MESSAGE);  
   i.putExtra(FriendInfo.USERNAME, StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom()));
   i.putExtra(FriendInfo.MESSAGE, message.getBody());
   i.putExtra("who", "1");
   sendBroadcast(i);
```

And the receiving end in the activity class:

```
public class newMessage extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
@Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {    
    String action = intent.getAction();
       if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(IMService.NEW_MESSAGE)){    
          Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
          String username = extra.getString(FriendInfo.USERNAME);   
          String message = extra.getString(FriendInfo.MESSAGE);
          String who = extra.getString("who");
         }
   }
}
```

The BroadcastReceiver is defined within an Activity.  I am registering the receiver in the onCreate method of the Activity, not in the Manifest file.

I'm stumped as to why it won't rec. anything.

Any insight?

**EDIT**
Registering takes place as follows:

```
 registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(IMService.NEW_MESSAGE));
```

Where "messageReceiver" is defined as

```
private newMessage messageReceiver = new newMessage();
```

IMService.NEW_MESSAGE is merely a string = "NewMessage"

Comment: how do you register your receiver?

Comment: where and how do you declare the IntentFilter on your activity?

Comment: IntentFilter shouldn't be involved here for the activity, receiver is what works here.

Comment: ouh, always register my receivers with registerReceiver(aReceiver, aIntentFilter);  is the bad way?

Comment: @Vladimir @Franco I am registering the receiver using registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(IMService.NEW_MESSAGE));

Comment: strange, i do in the same way, did you declare and undeclare your receivers on onResume() and onPause(), the message received runs on other thread, so, check it that too

Comment: Franco....turns out that I shouldn't have registered in the onCreate method.  I moved reg/unreg to the onResume and onPause respectively and things are going smoothly now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is specific to the set up, or if it is a fix in general, but moving the `register/unregister` to the `onResume/onPause` `_respectively_` and not registering in the `onCreate` solved the problem for me.

Comment: You can just as easily register the receiver in your AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this two things:

1. Use manifest file to register receiver(but it barely helps)
2. Try make your Receiver a regular class, not inner one.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for the help.  I'll be moving it to it's own class later on - thought about it after you mentioned it and it seems like the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Inner class broadcast receiver will not be able to handle broadcast(means it unable to locate that class ).
So make it as a separate class

Definitely it will work.